# How to encrypt iOS files (e.g. PDFs) from user access?

Tags: ios

Is there a way to secure files downloaded within an app to prevent them from being accessed by the user via a jail broken device, or something like iExplorer when the device is plugged into a computer ?

I'm primarily thinking of things like PDF files, and have considered encrypting them in someway and then storing the data in an sqlite database. The other thing I've looked into is 'NSDataWritingFileProtectionComplete' but that only seems to encrypt data when the phone is locked.

Any suggestions more than welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Once the device is jail broken the security of the device cannot be guaranteed ( this is also true with an Android and giving yourself ability to run stuff as root ) you should be able to encrypt the files by implementing your own encrypting method if there is nothing offered by the SDK.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the CCCrypt library to encrypt your data.

These links should guide you in the right direction:

http://aptogo.co.uk/2010/07/protecting-resources/

http://www.raywenderlich.com/6475/basic-security-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1

Comment: Thanks Bobby, very useful. I also found the following page which has some good info about encrypting data:
http://robnapier.net/blog/aes-commoncrypto-564

Comment: @AndyDunn can you let me know what you ended up implementing

Answer (score 1):

If it's just PDF files, the easiest way to secure them is to password-protect the files.  Your app can use the password to open them, but people who grab the files from the device won't be able to.